# What is the equivalent of CacheDependency's cacheKeys parameter in .NET 4's System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: .net

I am migrating some old .NET 3.5 code to .NET 4. What is the equivalent of the below code in terms of the usage of the cacheKey parameter to CacheDependency (with value "xyz" in my example)?

```
var webCache = new System.Web.Caching.Cache();
webCache.Insert("foo", "bar", new CacheDependency(null, new [] { "xyz" }), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is the MemoryCache's CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor method:

```
var memoryCache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;
var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy {
    ChangeMonitors = 
        {
            memoryCache.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(new[] { "xyz" })
        }
};
memoryCache.Add("foo", "bar", cacheItemPolicy);
```